# Can crystal reports display input in html form?

Tags: html, visual-studio, crystal-reports

If I have a varchar column in a SqlServer db containg html, is there any way that crystal reports can display it the way a brower would?

For example, if the field contains the string

```
<b> <u> This is my text. </u>  </b>
```

crystal would know to display it as

**This is my text.**

I am using the crystal reports that comes with vs2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which version that is, but you should be able to do something along these lines:

1. Right-click the field, select "Format Field"
2. Select the "Paragraph Formatting" or "Paragraph" tab.
3. Find the "Text interpretation" dropdown, and instead of `none`, select `HTML text`.

It might be slightly different depending on the version you are using, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Interesting. This produced   'This is my text. b This is my text.' where the second 'This is my text' was underlined and it looked like the whole thing was bold.

Comment: Ok, I took out all spaces between the html tags. So  <b><u> This is my text. </u></b> worked! Thanks so much!